# What is the best sdk to use to track user/game events through game in Cocos2d-x V3 ?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

What is the best sdk to use to track user/game events through game in Cocos2d-x V3 ? Is there any drag'n'drop sdk for cocos2d-x ( mixpanel is not supported by default ).

Answer (score 0):

For me the best event tracking tool is Google Analytics for [iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?hl=pl) and [Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/?hl=pl).
You can also give a try to [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/solutions/analytics).
Tutorial Google Analytics for Cocos2dx [iOS](http://www.redtgames.com/blog/integrating-google-analytics-to-cocos2d-x-game/) and [Android](https://github.com/lvklabs/gaan).